# Difference between ordered and unordered (rooted) trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am reading algorithms by Robert Sedwick. Some definitions from the book are shown below.

> A tree (also an ordered tree) is a node (called the root) connected to
>   a sequence of disjoint trees. Such a sequence is called a forest.
>
> A rooted tree (or unordered tree) is a node (called the root)
>   connected to a multiset of rooted trees. (such a multiset is called an
>   unordered forest.

My questions on the above text are

1. I am having difficutlty in understanding above defintions.  Can any one please explain with examples.
2. What does author mean by disjoint trees?
3. What does author mean by multiset rooted trees?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: The difference between ordered and unordered trees is that subtrees have (or have not) an order. Every node has a first, a second, an nth subtree: T1, T2, ..., Tn in one case (and just n subtrees in the other case).

Answer (score 4):

1. A tree by this definition is more or less what we normally understand by tree: a node connected to an ordered sequence of (sub)trees. It's a recursive definition: if the sequence is empty, the node is called *leaf,* and if not, each of the tree in the sequence is also "a node connected to an ordered sequence of (sub)trees."
2. By disjoint the author means that the subtrees don't have nodes in common.
3. The definition means that the subtrees of a rooted tree are not in a particular order and that they may be repeated. A [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is kind of like a set that allows multiples.

An ordered tree (a "tree" of the first definition) has the subtrees in a particular order, and the subtree sequence cannot contain the same tree twice, because the subtrees must be disjoint. A rooted tree does not have these restrictions; by this definition a root might have a subtree twice, in a structure that resembles a cycle.

I don't have Sedwick's book to check if or why this definition makes sense; a more common definition or rooted tree would use a normal set for subtrees, rather than a multiset. Perhaps the intention is to allow multiple links between a node and its children while disallowing other kinds of cycles, such as links between siblings and cousins.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. By the way one more question what is free trees and unrooted trees?

Comment: Once you have a tree, you can pick any node as the root and it will still be a tree. A "free" or "unrooted" tree is a tree where no node has been selected as the root. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_tree

Comment: *"A **normal** tree has the subtrees in a particular order"*. I guess you mean an **ordered tree**, not normal. What is normal/default for one (author) is not for another.

Comment: *"and the subtrees **cannot be repeated** because they must be disjoint"*. Disjoint subtrees does not mean that they can't be repeated. Example: a tree with root and just 3 subtrees (each of a single node) has 3 disjoint yet identical subtrees.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks, substituted ordered for normal.

Comment: @ypercube A multiset (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) contains multiples of the same object; not multiples of identical copies of the object. A "rooted tree" by the second definition could have as the subtree set a multiset of one node repeated twice, forming a structure that to me sounds like a cycle. I don't have Sedwick's book so I could look up how or why this definition makes sense.

Comment: Well, I think you are no wrong or (more probably) you mean something else from what I understand. Trees definitely have no cycles. My understanding is that both ordered and unordered trees can have subtrees that are identical copies of the same object.

Comment: Yes, that would be the case if a "rooted tree" was defined with a set of subtrees, but Sedwick uses a *multiset*. Perhaps the intention is to allow multiple connections between a node and its children while disallowing other kinds of cycles, such as links between siblings.

Comment: No, the intention is to allow a node to have 2 or more same subtrees (a set cannot have 2 same objects, a multiset can)